# Do the The Hobbit films deliberately quote The Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit

My wife and I are well versed in the dialogue from the Lord of the Rings movies. We are not quite so enthusiastic about The Hobbit movies, but recently we noticed something odd while watching the Battle of Five Armies: the movie seems to quote other Lord of the Rings movies. Here are some examples:

In the Battle of Five Armies:

> Galadriel (to Sauron/Necromancer): "You have no power here!"
>
> Legolas (to Tauriel at the gates of Angmar): "These bats are bred for a single purpose ... For war."

In The Two Towers:

> Saruman (through the mouth of Theoden, to Gandalf): "You have no power here, Gandalf the Grey!"
>
> Aragorn (to Theoden): "It is an army bred for a single purpose: to destroy the world of men."

Are these references intentional, or just a symptom of having the same writers with the same mannerisms?

Are there any other almost direct quotes we missed?

Comment: In Battle of the Five Armies, Bilbo says to a dying Thorin "The eagles are coming". Pippin also says this in RotK. I noticed a few more similar lines but can't remember at the moment.

Comment: I don't think these are likely to be quotes of each other, rather just similar language being used.

Comment: Pippin explicitly references his memories of Bilbo's story (at least in the book; it's many years since last I saw the films).